# How to one-string code write to multi-strings

Tags: python

I am a new to python. I have a dictonary and a list.
like this:

```
dict1 = {'123@123.com': 'John Smith', '1234@1234.com': 'James Brown'}
list1 = ['123@123.com', '1234@1234.com', '987@987.com']
```

I need to compare email from the list with key from dictonary, if it's the same, then print value from dictonary.

I found a great decision:

```
result = {k:dict1[k] for k in list1 if k in dict1}
```

It's returns dictonary.

But how to rewrite this in multiline view? I need to add: elif value from list1 != key from dict1 then print value from list1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
dict1 = {'123@123.com': 'John Smith', '1234@1234.com': 'James Brown'}
list1 = ['123@123.com', '1234@1234.com', '987@987.com']
output = {}
for k in list1:
    if dict1.get(k,0):
        print(dict1[k])
        output[k] = dict1[k]
    else:
        print(k)
        output[k] = "unknown"
print(output)
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats a great way too. Is it possible to put output of the print(dict1[k]) and print(k) to the list for example?

Comment: I didn't understand what you wanted to do

Comment: I want something like this: result = ['John Smith', 'James Brown', '987@987.com'] or like this result = {'123@123.com': 'John Smith', '1234@1234.com': 'James Brown', '987@987.com': 'unknown'}

Comment: I have edited the code. Please check

Comment: Yes, its what i need. Thank you! You are the best.))

Answer (score 2):

Without a comprehension:

```
for email in list1:
    if email not in dict1:
        print(email)

# Output
987@987.com
```

Or with a comprehension:

```
print(*[email for email in list1 if email not in dict1], sep='\n')

# Output
987@987.com
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this one liner?

```
dict1 = {'123@123.com': 'John Smith', '1234@1234.com': 'James Brown'}
list1 = ['123@123.com', '1234@1234.com', '987@987.com']
print('\n'.join(list(filter(lambda x:x not in dict1,list1))))
```

**output:**

```
987@987.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of emails not found in dict1 using list comprehension:

```
not_found = [i for i in list1 if i not in dict1]
```

You can run for loop on this "not_found" var.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a better control over your data processing if you convert your dict comprehension into a classical for-loop like so:

```py
results = {}
for k in list1: 
   if k in dict1: 
      results[k] = dict1[k] 
   else:
      results[k] = "no name" 
      print(k)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to add email from else to dictonary 'results' with value 'no name' or something like this. Output will be: results = { '123@123.com': 'John Smith', '1234@1234.com': 'James Brown', '987@987.com': 'no name'

Comment: Of course, check this update I made https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71170530/revisions